# $\int_0^\pi \cos{mx}\cos{nx}\,\mathrm{d}x$, with $m$ and $n$ integers

Tags: trigonometry, definite-integrals

I can't figure out this integral at all. Integrating gave the following

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{2}[\frac{\sin((m-n)x)}{m-n}+\frac{\sin((m+n)x)}{m+n}],
\end{equation}

but when I evaluate it from $0$ to $\pi$ I get $0$ both when $m=n$ and $m\neq n$. Instead, it should be that the value of the integral when $m=n$ is $\frac{\pi}{2}$. My reasoning is that since $m+n$ and $m-n$ are always integers, and the value of sine for any multiple of $\pi$ is zero, then both terms would be zero in all cases. Where am I mistaken?

Comment: hint ; period of $sin nx  sin mx  $  is equal to  period of  $ sin ^2 nx$ ?

Comment: Your method is correct for $m\ne n$, but for $m=n$ you get $\int_0^{\pi}\frac{1}{2}(1+\cos 2mx)dx$.